# when I connect proxy with selenium, It doesn't finish load

Tags: selenium, firefox, proxy

when I connect proxy with selenium, It doesn't finish load.

```
    public void startFireFoxWithProxy(String ip) {
    //Create a new Firefox profile
    FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
    //Then add the proxy setting to the Firefox profile we created
    ffprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", ip);
    ffprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "3128");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
}
```

After this connection Browser can't open any page.
It gets endless load...

If any one know about this problem.
Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ffprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.type",1);
ffprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", ip);
ffprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", port);
```